# map<K,V>::emplace where V constructor requires two parameters

Tags: dictionary, emplace

All the examples I can find for map::emplace use fairly simple types that have constructors that take a single argument, e.g.

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> foo;
foo.emplace("a", "b");
```

Suppose the value type constructor requires two parameters. Heck, let's really make it simple; suppose the value type is `std::pair<std::string, double>`. How do I use `std::map<string, pair<string, double> >::emplace()` to construct the value type in-place within the map?

I know this doesn't work:

```
std::map<std::string, std::pair<std::string, double> > foo;
foo.emplace("a", "b", 1.0);
```

At least, it fails loudly and at length on g++ 4.8.2. Is this even possible with C++11?

Comment: How about foo.emplace(std::make_pair("a", std::make_pair("b", 1.0)));

Answer (score 14):

My search-fu was weak. This is actually answered, in great and illuminating detail, [in another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553776/how-to-emplace-object-with-no-argument-constructor-into-stdmap).

The short answer:

```
foo.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
            std::forward_as_tuple("a"),
            std::forward_as_tuple("b", 1.0));
```